Failing to create a table using pyiceberg and Aws Glue
I'm trying to create new Iceberg table in AWS Glue:
glue_database_name = "alex_iceberg_test_db"
glue_catalog_uri = "s3://alex-iceberg-test-storage"
my_namespace = 'alex_db'


# Instantiate glue catalog
catalog = load_catalog("glue", **{"type": "glue", 
                                  "s3.region": "region", 
                                  "profile": "ALEX",
                                  "s3.access-key-id": "XXX",
                                  "s3.secret-access-key": "YYY"})


# Define the Iceberg schema
schema = Schema(
    NestedField(field_id=1, name="data", field_type=StringType(), required=False)        
)


## Create the Iceberg table using the Iceberg catalog
table_name = 'test_1'
catalog.create_table(
    identifier=f'{my_namespace}.{table_name}',
    location=glue_catalog_uri,
    schema=schema
)

and get the following error
OSError: When getting information for key 'metadata/00000-5df640cc-b47c-4b39-b578-07113565dab5.metadata.json' in bucket 'alex-iceberg-test-storage': AWS Error ACCESS_DENIED during HeadObject operation: No response body.

Inside alex-iceberg-test-storage I do have metadata but the 00000-5df640cc-b47c-4b39-b578-07113565dab5.metadata.json is not there.
Why does it searching for that file and who should create it?

are you using Boto3?

thanks for all the helpers!
eventually what worked is to set the correct credentials in ~/.aws/credentials and then
catalog = load_catalog("glue", **{"type": "glue", 
                                  "s3.region": "us-west-2", 
                                  "profile": "my_profile
                                  })

is working correctly (even without the s3.access-key-id and s3.secret-access-key)
